# Javascript trips up with daylight saving times

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following, which takes my datestring = "10/31/2016" and converts it to unixtimestamp, and then returns 1477872000 which is Mon, October 31st, 2016 12:00 AM.  However moment does some processing
thereafter and the daylight saving hours is tripping it up.  Is there anyway to handle this in my JS before it get sent to moment.;

```
var ts       = (new Date(datestring)).getTime() / 1000;
```

Comment: FYI, `10/31/2016` is not a standard date string supported by Javascript. Using it is not portable. You should use moment.js's date parser.

Comment: _"is tripping it up"_ isn't a very good problem description.

Comment: That's not the day that DST changes, so why do you think DST is affecting the result?

Comment: The JS converts the time to 12AM, when I change this to the same date at 1AM, everything works. Here in the UK, the DST changed that weekend.

Comment: Your JS only _seems_ to work because you're located in the UK yourself. It doesn't work for me (CEST). You should look into `Date.UTC()` and `moment.utc()`.

Comment: It changed on the 30th, not the 31st.  But that's besides the point.  You are saying that moment is doing something, but you don't show using moment in your code sample at all.  Voting to close.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from the help center.  Thanks.